# Entityframework select all childs related data when call parent

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have categories table which contains :

```
public partial class C_Categories
{
    public int CatId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentId { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<C_Node> C_Node { get; set; }
}
```

And i have node table which contains :

```
public partial class C_Node
{
    public int NodeId{ get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CatId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime PostDate { get; set; }

    public virtual C_Categories C_Categories { get; set; }
}
```

And my controller :

```
public ActionResult Index(int? catId)
{
    IQueryable<C_Node> moduleItems = db.C_Node;
    if (catId != null)
    {
        //here i want to check if category is parent , get all node related to his child categories
        moduleItems = moduleItems.Where(x => x.CatId == catId);
    }

    return View(moduleItems.ToList());
}
```

At my controller i want to check if category is parent , get all node table related to his child categories, 

I tried to use any , but it failed . 
 to explain my question : i have category : electronics and electronics have childs computers, mobiles . i have products on node table under computers and mobiles , if catId is electronics i want all products under its childs computers, mobiles

Comment: You only told what you want. What's your question?

Comment: I tried to use any , but it failed , to explain my question : i have category : electronics and electronics have childs computers, mobiles . i have products on node table under computers and mobiles , if catId is electronics i want all products under its childs computers, mobiles

Comment: **Show what you tried**, the code. Otherwise others will post the same thing as an answer and you're not getting anywhere.

Comment: I added an answer explained what i tried, please take a look on it

Comment: Thank you for your help, the answer of Mr Edward below is what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to find all the categories under the parent; if there are only 2 levels this is simple:

```
...

if (catId != null)
{
    // Find the child categories for which this is the parent    
    var childCatIds = db.C_Categories
     .Where(cat => cat.ParentId == catId)
     .Select(cat => cat.CatId)
     .ToList();
    if (childCatIds.Count == 0)
    // Not a parent category: Just find the items for the category as before
        moduleItems = moduleItems.Where(x => x.CatId == catId);
    else
        // Parent category: Find the items for the child categories
        moduleItems = moduleItems.Where(x => childCatIds.Contains(x.CatId));
}
```

If there are more than 2 levels, you will need to find the child ids recursively.

```
private List<int> GetChildCatIds(List<int> parentCatIds)
{
        var childCatIds = db.C_Categories
          .Where(cat => cat.ParentId.HasValue && parentCatIds.Contains(cat.ParentId.Value))
          .Select(cat => cat.CatId)
          .ToList();
        if (childCatIds.Count == 0)
            // Reached the end of the tree: no more children
            return parentCatIds;
        else
            // Recursive call to find the next child level:
            return GetChildCatIds(childCatIds);
}


...

if (catId != null)
{    
    var childCatIds = GetChildCatIds(new List<int>{catId.Value});
    moduleItems = moduleItems.Where(x => childCatIds.Contains(x.CatId));
}
```

Comment: Yes i have more than 2 levels, thank you very much for your answer :)

Comment: But this line : moduleItems.Where(x => childCatIds.Contains(x.CatId));, gives me an error

Comment: compile , it says : Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>.Contains(int)' has some invalid argument

Comment: sorry, this fixed the problem : moduleItems.Where(x => childCatIds.Contains(x.CatId ?? 0));

Comment: Now when run , this line : var childCatIds = db.C_Categories.Where(cat => parentCatIds.Contains(cat.CatId)).Select(cat => cat.CatId).ToList();  ......... gives me this error : An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Your 'fix' broke it! I have edited my answer. (The original compile error was because the CatId is nullable; also, I made a mistake on the select for the children in the recursive function, which I have corrected).

Comment: Thank you, and i found another simple solution, but it depends on how many level i know or i want , take alook on this code : moduleItems = moduleItems.Where(x => x.CatId == catId || x.C_Categories.ParentId == catId || x.C_Categories.C_Categories2.ParentId == catId)

Comment: If you have 3 levels or less your solution it will work. (It is not clear how you are populating C_Categories property, my solution does not need this property to be populated - give mine another try, I made another edit, I am doing it blind).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
moduleItems = dbcontext.C_Nodes.Where(n => n.CatId == catId);
```

Comment: that will get just products related to its category , I tried to use any , but it failed , to explain my question : i have category : electronics and electronics have childs computers, mobiles . i have products on node table under computers and mobiles , if catId is electronics i want all products under its childs computers, mobiles